# Chrome renderiza diferente con Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, chrome

Tengo una cuestión con Google Chrome.

Estoy armando una página con PHP y Bootstrap y probando en diferentes navegadores.
El tema es que en chrome, se pierden todos los estilos, y en los demás navegadores (Mozilla, Opera, Edge e IE), la página funciona perfectamente.

El código es el siguiente:
(Es básicamente el ejemplo de `navbar` de Bootstrap)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PAGINA</title>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <!-- <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <script src="bootstrap/jquery/jquery.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/popper/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head><header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ESTUDIO MANAGER</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

En principio probé con el CDN de bootstrap y funciona bien.

Sin embargo, necesito que todo pueda verse normalmente con los archivos de bootstrap descargados.

Por lo tanto, descargué los archivos de bootstrap y los enlacé en las carpetas correspondientes.
Luego, descargué desde el enlace del CDN, los scripts de jquery y ajax, y los transformé en archivos para hacer el enlace.

Todo funciona perfecto, excepto el archivo css, que si funciona si lo tengo enlazado directamente desde el http.

Por lo que necesito que funcione desde los archivos descargados.
Funciona en todos los demás navegadores, excepto en Google Chrome.

La pregunta principal es: ¿Por qué Chrome renderiza diferente que en los otros navegadores? ¿Por qué pierde estilos? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como uso Google Chrome para todas las páginas que estoy desarrollando, simplemente se ha llenado el caché de tantas veces que cambié Bootstrap ya sea de 3 a 4 y viceversa.

Simplemente solucioné el problema borrando el caché de Chrome y la página funciona, no solo en el resto de los navegadores, sino también en el que tenía el problema.

Gracias por leer.
Saludos!